# unable to load DLL 'iaStorAfsServiceApi.dll': The sepcified module couldn't be found

Tags: intel

Solution-
The solution which worked for me ----
go to control panel-> program & features ->click right on Intel Optane Pinning Explorer Extensions -> click on repair.
after the successful process..restart your machine.

Answer (score -1):

Solution-

The solution which worked for me ---- go to control panel-> program & features ->click right on Intel Optane Pinning Explorer Extensions -> click on repair. after the successful process..restart your machine.

Comment: you need not to uninstall anything but keep in mind when you update your  check whether rapid storage technology  is supported in your windows or not.